# GraphQL query string for requesting over http?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I am trying to work on java client that works with GraphQL Server where I want to send a query over http.

I looked at https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java but unable to find the solution I am looking for.

I am trying to find something similar to https://github.com/justinmakaila/Swift-GraphQL but for Java.

As per the swift example, it generates a `queryString` that client does a `POST` to graphql endpoint with to obtain the results. What is the equivalent in Java?

I basically want to generate a JSON query string from graphql client api listed above.

Comment: anyone found any tool for the job?

Answer (score 0):

> So graphql-java itself does not include a client, it is the
>   implementation of the GraphQL spec. As for the client, it doesn't even
>   care what implementation is on the server. (Bojan Tomic)

1. There's currently 2 available (but both have some drawbacks IMHO)
   [Apollo Android](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android) - Originally intended for Android, but equally usable
   in any Java project
2. [Shopify's GraphQL Java gen](https://github.com/Shopify/graphql_java_gen) - Similar to what
   wsdl2java does, for example, but not wrapped into a Maven plugin.
   Generates a nice client, but requires Ruby...